# How to sum the running total field value and formula field value in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

I want to add the running total field value and formula field value("Openbalnce"), the sum should be assigned to another formula field("Total").

In the formula editor of formula field("Total"),I have given as:

```
 {runningtotalvalue} + {formula field value("Openbalnce")}
```

The Formula field ("Openbalnce")value is assigned in code behind and running total field value is directly assigned.

It shows the error

```
"A number,date or time,date etc is required here".
```

Please help me out of this.

Comment: Maybe Openbalnce is a string. Try to convert it into a double using `CDBL` such as `CDBL({_field_}`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this. But there is still error popping. It shows: "The string is non-numeric".

Comment: I think you have a null value in your database particularly in the column openblnce. If that is the case, you should use a condition not to convert the null fields into a number

Comment: If you have running balance set to a currency, some DB can return with that currency symbol, that said, you may have that. Debug throught to see what values you have before the calculations are done

Comment: No,I am not populating the openbalnce field value from database. I am using the bellow code to assign the value:                            If DebitAmount > CreditAmount Then
   Dim OpenBalnce As Integer = DebitAmount - CreditAmount
 End If   ,                                                      where Debitamount and CreditAmount are integers which are taken from database

Comment: @Jonny, But The running balance field is not set to currency, and the value is properly set in running balance field. Think so the issue is with Formula field(openbalance).

Comment: @Arman, Thankyou Arman,CDBL is Working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is Working

```
({runningtotalvalue}) + CDBL({@"Openbalnce"})
```